# Google maps with overlapping markers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working with flutter (new to it) and have two markers which are overlapped (this is really necessary).

How can I let the user, for example, click on the marker (like a cluster one with these two markers), expand it in order to let the user choose which one he or she wants to click?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

try to implement clustering in your map:

[google map clustering](https://pub.dev/packages/clustering_google_maps)